# How can I compile a C++ file using LXTerminal in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu

I want to code using C++. How can I run my program using the terminal? It shows the following message.

> GCC: command not found

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to compile your code with gcc, you need to use `gcc` as the command. Commands in bash are case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Bash, like other Linux shells, is case sensitive: `GCC` is not the same as `gcc`, and you want to use `gcc`.

If even `gcc` doesn't work, it means:

- You didn't install it, which you should do with the following commands.

  ```
  sudo apt-get install build-essential
  sudo apt-get install gcc
  ```
- The command is not in your `$PATH`. In this case try first `env | grep path`, and then `gcc hello.c -o hello1`. If it doesn't work, find where `gcc` is with `find . -name gcc`, and add its path with `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/gcc`. (Replace `/path/to/gcc` with the path where `gcc` was find with the previous command.)